# Grails Spring security controller specific weird behaviour

Tags: grails, spring-security

We are using grails 2.3.3 and spring-security-cas:1.0.5

It all works perfectly until we deploy a new version, in which case, the browser sends the ticket again for some controllers.

Which controller will be sent the security check is random. Clearing the browser cache fixes the issue.

So when trying to reach some parts of the application, the user is taken to the application index page instead of the controller index page.

Here is what we have in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'myApp.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'myApp.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'myApp.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = "https://sso-cas/myCAS"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = "/login"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/myApp/j_spring_cas_security_check"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.useSingleSignout = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/myApp/secure/receptor'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'
```

Is there a way to avoid having to clear the user's cache after a redeploy?

Comment: If it's an issue with browser cache (as it sounds?) you might look into using the Cache Headers plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers) to tailor caching of your secure content.

Comment: thanks, the issue is at the authentication level though, I will try this nonetheless.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue from debugging the security plugin I found that the default authentication handler is being used instead of CAS 2013-12-05 10:51:21,602 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache  - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://127.0.0.1:8080/login]
2013-12-05 10:51:21,602 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Calling Authentication entry point.
2013-12-05 10:51:21,603 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy  - Redirecting to 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/auth'